# Почему не работает форма Angular?

Tags: angularjs

эйчтитипи://plnkr.co/edit/XyDPO8KENQjlhteFfzYw?p=preview
В данный момент код работает, но стоит только раскомментировать кусок, расположенный над формой, как перестает работать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Для вложенных форм в AngularJS используется директива `<ng-form>`.

Если для кнопки `<button>` не задан атрибут `type="button"`, то по-умолчанию она будет срабатывать как `submit` для формы.

В коде HTML (в примере на plnkr) не закрыт тег `<form>` для главной родительской формы, что "ломает" html.

- Добавить `type="button"` для кнопки во вложенной форме
- Проверить HTML-код и закрыть тег `form` для главной формы
- Для вложенных форм использовать `<ng-form>` вместо `<form>`

И все будет прекрасно работать я проверил на вашем коде )

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько путей исправления такого странного поведения:

1. Перенести объявление контроллера для дочерней формы чуть выше, например, для `div#dv1`
2. Дочернюю форму заменить на div c атрибутом `data-ng-form`

Так же хотелось посоветовать убрать для главной формы атрибут `action`, если подразумевается отправлять данные формы через AngularJS